# Как прятать URL картинки?

Tags: php

**Подскажите реализацию:** у меня есть изображение img на странице, мне нужно спрятать его URL. То есть что бы юзер при сохранении этой картинки сохранял php файл, а не саму картинку.

Чтобы не мог получить реальный URL изображения для последующей выкачки.

Может быть, я в чем-то ошибаюсь, интересны ваши способы решения этой задачи.

Comment: Все, что видит пользователь, можно сохранить. А знает он реальный адрес или нет, ему уже не важно. Есть картинка, она выведена, значит можно ее снять. Единственный путь - это, например, бить картинку скриптом на части и выводить в блок, в котором она будет "склеиваться". Но и в данном случае пазл можно в фотошопе собрать при желании (если уж картинка так будет человеку нужна).

Comment: Можно поюзать флэш как промежуточный контейнер, картинку выдавать с проверкой реферера. и по частям) Тогда это будет по крайней мере долго и скучно.

Comment: Я хочу защититься от того, чтобы изображения качали пачками. )
Если его будет очень сложно сохранить или даже придется юзать print screen, это нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть правда одна затея, которую не пробовал но должна работать... например, картинка выводится в браузер через пхп

```
echo "<img src='/kartinka.php?img=1a'>";
$_SESSION['1a']=true;
```

и дальше код... При обращении к скрипту он проверяет переменную `$_SESSION['1a']` и если она является истиной, то выводит картинку с индексом в массиве картинок равным 1a. (Об этом отдельно смотрите, как это делать). И тут же удаляет переменную или делает из нее

```
$_SESSION['1a']=false;
```

Все. Картинка выведется только в браузер при загрузке страницы. Взять ее отдельно, перейдя по ссылке, будет нельзя.

Comment: Конечно должна работать. Я практически этот способ и написал. ;)

Comment: только одно НО))) копирование прямо со страницы в граф редактор еще никто не запрещал))) отметили, нажали ctrl+c и пошли вставлять))

Comment: От парсеров с поддержкой куков не спасет, но вообще хорошая мысль.

Comment: Спасибо! это - то что нужно. Возьмусь за реализацию)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.jpg", "r");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
print($contents);
```

Comment: Угу и сам он как картинку будет выводить тогда.

Comment: Картинку можно скачать, но нельзя получить ее адрес.

Comment: showimg.php?img=codifiedFileName.jpg